# ¿Como dibujar linea en bitmap y picturebox en C#?

Tags: c#

En el momento de dibujar pixeles lo hace perfectamente, pero al dibujar la linea lo hace de forma equivocada, dibujando la linea fuera del rango del segundo pixel.

Les dejo el codigo del formulario por si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme, agradeceria mucho su apoyo.

```
namespace ProyectoGraficacion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Variables
        Bitmap Lienzo; 
        Boolean BanderaPixel, BanderaRecta; //Permite activar el dibujado del pixel
        Boolean BanderaPoligono;
        Color MiColor; //variable para asignar el color al dibujar
        List<Point> Pixeles = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> Auxiliar = new List<Point>();
        int Grosor;
        int INCX=0;
        int INCY=0;
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Lienzo = new Bitmap(pbAreaDeImagen.Width, pbAreaDeImagen.Height); //El tamaño del lienzo tiene que ser igual al del picture Box
            MiColor = Color.Black;            
        }

        private void MouseDibujarPixel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BanderaPoligono == true)
            {

                GrosorPixel(e.X, e.Y, MiColor, Grosor);
                Auxiliar.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

                if (Auxiliar.Count == Convert.ToInt32(cbLados.SelectedItem))
                {
                    Irregular(Auxiliar, Convert.ToInt32(cbLados.SelectedItem), MiColor);
                    Auxiliar.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (BanderaRecta == true)
            {
                GrosorPixel(e.X, e.Y, MiColor, Grosor);
                Pixeles.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

                if (Pixeles.Count == 2)
                {
                    Recta(Pixeles, MiColor);
                    Pixeles.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (BanderaPixel == true && Grosor>1)
            {
                GrosorPixel(e.X, e.Y, MiColor, Grosor);
            }
            else if (BanderaPixel == true)
            {
                Lienzo.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, MiColor);
            }
                pbAreaDeImagen.Image = Lienzo;
        }


        private void ActivarPixel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BanderaPixel = true;
        }

        private void LimpiarImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lienzo = new Bitmap(pbAreaDeImagen.Width, pbAreaDeImagen.Height);
            pbAreaDeImagen.Image = Lienzo;
        }

        private void ColorAzul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiColor = Color.Blue;
            ColorenUso.BackColor = MiColor;
        }

        private void ColorAmarillo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiColor = Color.Yellow;
            ColorenUso.BackColor = MiColor;
        }

        private void ColorRojo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiColor = Color.Red;
            ColorenUso.BackColor = MiColor;
        }

        private void ColorVerde_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MiColor = Color.Green;
            ColorenUso.BackColor = MiColor;
        }

        private void btnPaletaColores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.MiColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            }
        }

        public void GrosorPixel(int x, int y, Color MiColor, int Grosor)
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < Grosor; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Grosor; j++)
                {
                    ValidarPixel(x + i, y + j, MiColor);
                }
            }
        }

        private void cbGrosor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grosor = Convert.ToInt32(cbGrosor.SelectedItem);

        }

        public void ValidarPixel(int x, int y,Color MiColor)
        {
            if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x < pbAreaDeImagen.Width && y < pbAreaDeImagen.Height)
            {
                Lienzo.SetPixel(x , y , MiColor);
            }
        }

        private void btnTrazarLinea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BanderaRecta = true;
            BanderaPixel = false;
        }

        public void Recta(List<Point> Pixeles, Color MiColor)
        {
            float m, b, DX, DY;
            DX = Pixeles[1].X - Pixeles[0].Y;
            DY = Pixeles[1].Y - Pixeles[0].Y;
            m = DY / DX;
            b = Pixeles[0].Y - m * Pixeles[0].X;
            if (DX > 0)
            {
                INCX = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                INCX = -1;
            }
            if (DY > 0)
            {
                INCY = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                INCY = -1;
            }
            if(Math.Abs(DX)>Math.Abs(DY))
            { 
                for (int x = Pixeles[0].X; x <= Pixeles[1].X; x = x+INCX)
                {
                    y = m * x + b;
                    GrosorPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x),Convert.ToInt32(y), MiColor, Grosor);
                    //Lienzo.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(y)), MiColor);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int y = Pixeles[0].Y; y <= Pixeles[1].Y; y = y+INCY)
                {
                    x = (y - b) / m;
                    GrosorPixel(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y), MiColor, Grosor);
                    //Lienzo.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(x)), Convert.ToInt32(y), MiColor);
                }
            }
        }



        public void Irregular(List<Point> Pixeles, int Lados, Color MiColor)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= Lados-1; i++)
            {
                Auxiliar[0] = Pixeles[i];
                Auxiliar[i] = Pixeles[i + 1];
                Recta(Auxiliar, MiColor);
            }
                Auxiliar[0] = Pixeles[Lados-1];
                Auxiliar[1] = Pixeles[0];
                Recta(Auxiliar, MiColor);

        }

         private void AdaptarPantalla(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbAreaDeImagen.Width = this.Width - 50;
            pbAreaDeImagen.Height = this.Height - 225;
            btnLimpiarImagen.Top = this.Height - 100;
            btnLimpiarImagen.Left = this.Width - 120;
            gbColores.Left = this.Width - 270;
            Lienzo = new Bitmap(pbAreaDeImagen.Width, pbAreaDeImagen.Height);
        }

         private void btnPoligono_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

             BanderaPixel = false;
             BanderaRecta = false;
             BanderaPoligono = true;
         }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Alan. Bienvenido. Me temo que haría falta algo más de información para poder ayudarte. ¿A los eventos de qué controles tienes asociados los métodos definidos en tu código? (Algunos parecen obvios pero otros no tanto) ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que esperas? ¿Cuál es el que estás obteniendo en su lugar?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error tipográfico en tu método `Recta`. Cuando calculas la diferencia en X, en tu código tienes `DX = Pixeles[1].X - Pixeles[0].Y;`. Debería ser `DX = Pixeles[1].X - Pixeles[0].X;`